# Pandas Series - > Dataframe. Create columns from rows and fill nonmatching with zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a couple columns. I then pull df[reason] and get the series

```
some text 1                                          0.1178
Other string                                         0.0732
another string                                       0.0534

Name: reason, dtype: float64
```

What I'd like to convert this to is a dataframe to something that looks like:

```
                              some text 1    Other string another string
some text 1                   0.1178         0            0
Other string text             0              0.0732       0
another string here           0              0            0.0534
```

How do I duplicate the rows as columns and fill the non matching row/columns with 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [`np.diag`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html):

```
>>> ts
some text 1       0.1178
Other string      0.0732
another string    0.0534
dtype: float64
>>> DataFrame(np.diag(ts), columns=ts.index, index=ts.index)
                some text 1  Other string  another string
some text 1          0.1178        0.0000          0.0000
Other string         0.0000        0.0732          0.0000
another string       0.0000        0.0000          0.0534
```

Comment: Ah, did not know about diag! Thanks!